# how to create a single-use link in Drupal 8

Tags: module, drupal-8

I have to send several emails (3000) from drupal 8. Each email must have a single-use link that points to the same page. All emails are saved in a custom entity (not the registered users of the site).

When the user clicks on the mail link I have to check that the link has not already been used.

I suppose that in addition to the mail, you have to save a single parameter in the custom entity (token?). And when the user clicks on the email link I look if the parameter exists and if it has not already been used.

How can I do that?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation depends on what exactly you are going to do. The simplest way to ensure than the link was used only once is to set a cookie. Sure, it's not the most reliable way (you can delete cookie or visit the same link from different device/browser), but it can be enough for certain scenarios.

If you need more reliable solution, I'd suggest you to implement a custom [route controller](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/introductory-drupal-8-routes-and-controllers-example) that accepts a token as a url parameter and check it against your tokens.
You can store them as an array ['token' => 'some_hash', 'used' => 0] in [Drupal sates](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/state-api/overview)